# Coq Notation Syntax error: [term level 200] expected after [term level 200] (in [term])

Tags: coq

I'm confused about Notations in Coq/Gallina.
I have turned my problem into a minimal example:
Why in the following the last line does not work?

```
Definition nOp (a b:nat) := a.
Notation "'nOpOpen' a b 'nOpClose'" := (nOp a b).
Definition foo0 := (nOp 1 0).
Definition foo1 := (nOpOpen 1 0 nOpClose).
//this last line gives
//Syntax error: [term level 200] expected after [term level 200] (in [term]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the levels in this way worked for me:

```
Notation "'nOpOpen' a b 'nOpClose'" := (nOp a b) 
  (at level 10, a at next level, b at next level).
```